# Is there any functions can access single value of smbios with protocol technique?

Tags: bios, uefi

I am newbie to uefi and trying to access smbios values with protocol technique. I have checked up the UEFI and SMBIOS spec, but found nothing with them.

I know that there is one function called pci.read() which can access one value in the pci area of memory each time when using protocols to deal with pci devices. It seems that there is no alike function to read one value each time to deal with smbios protocols?

What I found in the specs which is similar is GetNext(), but this function only outputs three values of header. I am wonder if there is any way to read single value each time so I can instantly Print() the value? Or put memory values of smbios into an array?

Answer (score 0):

**SMBIOS** is nothing more to UEFI than a pointer to a configuration table (reachable through the UEFI System Table, and identified by the specified GUID).

There *is* an `EFI_SMBIOS_PROTOCOL`, but it is part of the PI (Platform Initialization) specification, not UEFI - so cannot be considered a portable interface. The latest version of the PI specification (currently 1.7) can be downloaded from https://uefi.org/specifications.

Otherwise, grab the pointer from the system table and parse the structure manually. The size of the structure table can be read from the SMBIOS entry point.

Comment: Than you for answering, but I gave up using protocol to access smbios data. I use EfiGetSystemConfigurationTable instead. It's much faster and easier to do.

Comment: Sadly, I think that's the best option.